# Xamarin.forms Navigation drawer same item click issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I am stuck while i am clicking on navigation drawer item and going to that page. I cannot click that item again. It shows it selected. I want to click that option again. Please suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want but I know that to unselect an item in a listview for example, you have to set the SelectedItem property of the listview to null. Otherwise the item stay selected.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have selected your item, you must deselect it once you navigated.

Comment: how to deselect it while navigationg